# How to set an element of an array to an empty string

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to be able to not pass through the ampersand in the second last element in the below array to what is passed to execvp. What I was trying to do was get the size of the array and then set the second last element to an empty string, however the size I get returned is 1 (I believe this is because that's the size of the first character in what I am pointing to). Could anyone suggest how I can do this or an alternative option.

```
int main()
{
    char *cmd = "ls";
    char *argv[4];
    char **args = argv;
    argv[0] = "sleep";
    argv[1] = "3";
    argv[2] = "&";
    argv[3] = NULL;

    int n = sizeof(args) / sizeof(argv[0]);
    printf("size: %d\n", n);
    execvp(cmd, argv);
}
```

Comment: Empty string is just `""` (effectively an array with just the `'\0'` character). Not sure about what you trying to do or if the empty string is a solution though.

Comment: `args` is a pointer and `argv[0]` is a pointer, and those have the same size, which is why `n` is coming up as 1. In order to figure out the second-to-last element, you probably have to save the array size somewhere.

Comment: To get the size of the array, you need `sizeof(argv)/sizeof(argv[0])`

Comment: Or just `sizeof argv / sizeof *argv`. I prefer using no surrounding parens, as I rarely need the size of a *type* directly, and often want the specific size of a specific var or dereferenced pointer. Omitting the parens will trip a compile-time error if the operator argument is a type (ex: `sizeof int` = bad mojo), and I generally want to know if that happens (by accident or otherwise).

Comment: _"I want to be able to **not** pass through the ampersand"_ - I don't understand this. If you don't want it there, just remove it.

Comment: Could clarify the reason for passing the ampersand or not passing it ? Because your final goal might be reached by other means.

Comment: _Just a guess_: you're passing `&` as the last argument because you want to run the command _detached_ (just as you would do in the shell). If so, this won't work. To do this from C, you'd want: `pid_t pid = fork(); if (pid == 0) execvp(...);`

Comment: Also, it's not clear if you're trying to execute `ls` or `sleep 3`. That's because `cmd` is set to `ls` and `argv` uses `sleep`. Due to the nature of how `execvp` works, generally, you want `cmd` to have the same value as `argv[0]`

Comment: @WhozCraig *I prefer using no surrounding parens*  I prefer to use parenthesis on `sizeof()` **always**.  As the parenthesis are sometimes required, this makes all uses of `sizeof()` identical.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `sizeof` is a unary operator, not a function, and not a macro. The parentheses are needed only for types for syntax reasons. Do you surround any operand of a unary operator with parentheses? This will make all uses of unary operators identical.

Comment: @thebusybee  Human minds recognize patterns, not particulars.  Using a consistent form improves code readability significantly and therefore reduces the chances of bugs.  Since parenthesis are **required** for some usages of `sizeof()`, to use  `sizeof()` consistently requires the use of parenthesis at all times.  Note that parenthesis are not required for unary operators in general, so your strawman is lame.  Perhaps you should spend your time thinking about how you could improve the readability of the code you write instead of making up incorrect reasons to throw rocks at those who do.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do care **a lot** about readability. And around here, we always stumble over these parentheses, because we think "how can this by a type"? Just because some don't know the the correct usage, I don't need to join them. Let's make the world better by constantly pointing out how to improve.